# Deleting a Row Error in MYSQL Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am Getting and Error While Deleting a Row from MYSQL Database Table using Python "Could Not Process Parameters" can any one help me with this please.

My Code is as Follows

import mysql.connector as server

```
def delete_button(self):
  

    try:
        connection = server.connect(host='localhost',
                                    user='root',
                                    password='',
                                    database='alc')

        command_handler = connection.cursor()


        command_handler.execute("DELETE FROM alc_staff WHERE Employee_Code = %s",self.emp_code_var.get())


        


      
        messagebox.showinfo('Server', 'Record Deleted From Database')

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()




    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Server', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the Query like this:

```
    command_handler.execute("DELETE FROM alc_staff WHERE Employee_Code = %s" % self.emp_code_var.get())
```

or use the f-Strings and pack your get method into a variable.

```
    empCode = self.emp_colde_var.get()
    command_handler.execute(f"DELETE FROM alc_staff WHERE Employee_Code = {empCode}")
```